# I am trying to use a Subtype Object in place of a Supertype object but it is not working?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have created two objects T_PERSONS,T_BUSINESS_PERSON where T_BUSINESS PERSON is a subtype and T_PERSONS is a supertype.

---Creating T_PERSONS OBJECT---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE T_PERSONS AS OBJECT
( id integer,
 first_name varchar2(10),
 last_name varchar2(10),
 dob DATE,
 phone varchar2(12),
 address t_address,
 ) NOT FINAL;
```

---Creating T_BUSINESS_PERSON OBJECT---

```
CREATE TYPE t_business_person UNDER t_persons 
(title varchar2(20),
 company varchar2(20)
 );
```

Now I created an object table object_customers

```
CREATE TABLE object_customers OF t_persons
```

INSERTING DATA INTO object_customers

```
 INSERT INTO object_customers VALUES
 (t_persons(1,'Jason','Bond','03-APR-1955','800-555-1211',
  t_address('21 New  Street','Anytown','CA','12345')
  ));
```

in this case,data has been inserted properly

```
 INSERT INTO object_customers VALUES
 (t_business_person(2,'Steve','Edwards','03-MAR-1955','800-555-1212',
  t_address('1 Market  Street','Anytown','VA','12345'),'Manager','XYZ Corp'
  ));
```

Now in this case an error has occured

```
Error-attribute or element value is larger than specified in type.
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

The second insertion will work only if you create the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE object_customers OF t_business_person;
```

Click here to read more about [NOTFINAL](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0620__Object-Oriented/NOTFINALclause.htm) clause.